# Англійські відповідники: "адвокатське бюро" та "адвокатське об’єднання"

Tags: терміни, словосполучення

Адвокатське бюро є юридичною особою, створеною одним адвокатом, а адвокатське об’єднання — двома або більше адвокатами. Чи словосполучення “адвокатське бюро” та “адвокатське об’єднання” перекладаються англійською однаково (“law firm”)? Або ж є різні відповідники?

Comment: Тільки зараз помітив це запитання. Запитання, що стосуються перекладів з української на інші мови, вважаються офф-топіком. Ключове положення: користувачі сайту *«Українська мова»*.Stack Exchange знаються на… *українській мові*. Якщо для того, щоб відповісти на запитання, треба знатися на чомусь іншому (англійській мові або, до прикладу, квантовій фізиці) — таке запитання має дуже незначні шанси отримати відповідь саме на сайті «Українська мова».